# PYQT and reading file to Qtextedit

Tags: python, pyqt

Im using PyQt4 and having trouble opening a text file, and displaying it to Qtextedit.  The "print f + "  this needs to go in textedit" prints that its there, but the open says that it isn't.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
def convertDirectory(self):
    directoryPath = self.selectFilecsvtoxml()
    cmd = ('python loginformationExtractor.py '
           +str(directoryPath))
    print cmd + "   this is executable command"
    os.system(cmd)

    for file_name in os.listdir(directoryPath):
        print (directoryPath) + "****" + file_name

        if file_name.endswith(".txt"):
            f = file_name
            print f + "  this needs to go in textedit"

            readMe = open(f,'r').read()
            self.textEdit.setText(readMe)
```

My error/printout:

```
/Users/eeamesX/work/data/releaseOct27****UUIDreadout.txt
UUIDreadout.txt  this needs to go in textedit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eeamesX/PycharmProjects/Workmain/windows.py", line 2792, in convertDirectory
    readMe = open(f,'r').read()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'UUIDreadout.txt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def convertDirectory(self):
    directoryPath = self.selectFilecsvtoxml()
    cmd = ('python loginformationExtractor.py '
           +str(directoryPath))
    print cmd + "   this is executable command"
    os.system(cmd)

    for file_name in os.listdir(directoryPath):
        print (directoryPath) + "****" + file_name

        if file_name.endswith(".txt"):
            f = os.path.join(directoryPath, file_name)
            print f + "  this needs to go in textedit"

            readMe = open(f,'r').read()
            self.textEdit.setText(readMe
```

I think you forgot to add dir path file.